# contour integration over unit circle when the integral is not analytic

Tags: integration

what is $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}dz$ where z is a complex number. it is not analytic since there is a singularity at $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The integral you wrote is not a contour integral.